# Beamer box with image - how do I achieve this in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tcolorbox, tikz-styles

I wish to have a coloured box with an encircled image at the top left(see pic). How do I achieve this in LaTeX for a beamer presentation[image]?

Comment: Have a look at the tcolorbox package, especially the "graphical overlay".

Comment: I thought so too. But unable to get it done. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
notitle,
enhanced,
overlay={\path[circle, fill stretch image*={width=1cm}{frog}] ([xshift=2cm]frame.north west) circle(1cm);},
top=1cm,
]

\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]